# create a versioned jar in maven

Tags: maven-2, maven-scm

I want to create a maven goal which will create versioned jar like when I create a jar first time it will create a jar with version 1.0 then second time create a jar with version 1.1 then 1.2 and so on... means if latest jar version is 1.2 then next time when I build it, it will create a jar with version 1.3. is it possible?

or I need to provide the jar with version to create each time I build a jar. 
or I need to create a maven goal which will do all this,  is it possible ? If there is some solution for this then please guide me.

**Update:**

As per the following answer I have used buildnumber-maven-plugin with timestamp to create build with timestamp and it works as expected but when I am trying to use revision number along with build it's throwing exception:

```
can not get revision from SCM repositoty ,No provider git
```

My pom.xml includes:

```
  <scm>

    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/user/app.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:user/app.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/user/app.git</url>
</scm>
```

is there any plugin is needed because I have just included  details and buildnumber plugin.

Comment: You are aware of a thing like 1.0-SNAPSHOT's in Maven which exactly creates a timestamp for every build you creating. Are you using a repo manager? may be you can elaborate a little bit more to see what you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) can help you to build a new version of an artifact (and incrementing automatically the `<version>`.

But, I'm not sure this what you need, because it's quite unusual to create a new release on every build.

So I suggest you the [maven-buildnumber-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) which allows you to append something like a build number (or a timestamp to the artifact name).